# Animations while opening/ closing a FragmentAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I want to play back a custom animation when attaching a fragment to an activity, containing a FragmentPager. Unfortunately the normal way using `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(int, int)` does only work partially. Regardless what I do just the out animation or in animation of the transition is shown.

Here is what I have so far:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout, R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    transaction.add(R.id.fragmentSpace, hostingFragment, CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

In this case just the in animation of the new fragment is shown, the old fragment stays visible under the newly attached one. Together with that no animation is played when the back stack is popped.

Replacing the `transaction.add(..)` with `transaction.replace(..)` helps in terms of removing the underlying Fragment, but leaves still the problem that its out animation is not shown. In this case the underlying Fragment just disappears. At least the pop animation is shown in the .replace case.

For an example project see: [github](https://github.com/imhoff/FragmentPager/tree/animations) (animations branch)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `remove()` or `replace()` on the fragment transaction to get rid of the other fragment.

Comment: As I mentioned above: transaction.replace() doesn't help either. It fails to display the out animation of the replaced fragment. Just tested the combo remove(Fragment) and add(Fragment) but its really the same as calling replace.